# how to fix "nodetool: Failed to connect to 'localhost:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'."

Tags: java, cassandra

I installed Cassandra and it is working fine before but as soon as I update java 1.8 to java 16 I got this error
even though I run

`systemctl status cassandra`

it says Unit cassandra.service could not be found

here is the logs of cassandra

```
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  PropertiesUtil:65 - loadProperties - file does not exist, skipping ... /opt/apigee/customer//pod/default.properties
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  PropertiesUtil:65 - loadProperties - file does not exist, skipping ... /opt/apigee/customer//pod/default.properties
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  PropertiesUtil:65 - loadProperties - file does not exist, skipping ... /opt/apigee/customer//org/default.properties
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  PropertiesUtil:65 - loadProperties - file does not exist, skipping ... /opt/apigee/customer//org/default.properties
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  PropertiesUtil:65 - loadProperties - file does not exist, skipping ... /opt/apigee/customer//host/default.properties
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  PropertiesUtil:65 - loadProperties - file does not exist, skipping ... /opt/apigee/customer//host/node-2.properties
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  Tokenizer:104 - Tokenization Done
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  ZipCompare:59 - Comparing /opt/apigee/data/apigee-cassandra/config_backup_20210729_042017.zip with /opt/apigee/data/apigee-cassandra/newconfig_backup_20210729_042018.zip:
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  ZipCompare:111 - 19 entries matched
2021-07-29 04:20:18 INFO  ConfigUtil:74 - Removing old backup files as there is no change /opt/apigee/data/apigee-cassandra/config_backup_20210729_042017.zip
```

if i run `nodetool status`
it says `nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.`

and if i restart the service using ```apigee-all restart``
[image: dead]

thanks for any guidance or help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cassandra does not work with Java 16.

Cassandra versions pre-4.0 only supports Java 8. Cassandra 4.0 supports Java 8 + Java 11 which is tagged "experimental" (although there's active discussion about adopting full support). Cheers!

Comment: thanks for responding i rolled back to java 1.8 but still cassandra is dead

Comment: If you update your question and post the error there, I'd be happy to help you diagnose it. Cheers!

Comment: It looks like you posted the output of your app restart. You need to look at your Cassandra logs to determine why it failed to start. Cheers!